# Extracting Totals and Summary of raw data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I wonder if someone may be able to help.

I have a sheet with a list of events a person (email address) has attended and I'd like to extract/summarize the data in columns either at the end or on a new sheet.

For each email calculate / display:

- "Total number of all events booked". I do this today using `=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$25140, D2)`
- "Total number of events booked by "Category of Event"
- "Total number of Donations"
- Total number of times (row(s)) this person has made a "Donation to Fund". For blank display 0.
- "Sum of "Donation to Fund". If no amount state €0

Example sheet

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using PivotTables? At face value they would make all of those calculations and many more trivially easy to produce - this sort of summarisation is exactly what they are designed for.

Comment: Thanks AdamV.  Looks interest.  Will take a look.